# Apply scss value at class level using typescript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, sass

```
let getClasses = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar');
    for (var i = 0; i < getClasses.length; i += 1) {
        getClasses[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
```

i have this piece of code but what it does is it changes the display property of the div at element level and not at class level.
so when my value again changes at class level in the media query it does not get applied since it doesnt have the required priority and the value of the element remains the same.

Comment: Do you know the difference between SCSS and CSS? And which can be used with JS?

Comment: i do know the difference between the two but i am not aware which one can be used with JS.
and also i want to use it with typescript not javascript

Comment: SCSS is to CSS what Typescript is to JavaScript. Both SCSS and Typescript are just fancy languages which still get "compiled" to their later counterparts. JS interacts with CSS. Typescript _is_ Javascript, with fancy stuff added on.

Comment: I'd recommend learning how to use the DOM with JS, before using Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a class that changes the display like:

```
.block-display{
    display: block;
 }
```

Then in your javascript code, you add the class instead like:

```
let getClasses = document.querySelector('.sidebar')
for (let i = 0; i < getClasses.length; i++){
    let class = getClasses[i]
    class.classList.add('block-display')
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Definitely a  better approach - however missing quotation marks on the line that reads `class.classList.add(block-display)` it should be     `class.classList.add('block-display')`

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Made the changes